# C# - Adding objects dynamically (adding dynamic property names)

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, structure, expandoobject

I'm trying to create some dynamic `ExpandoObject`. I've encountered a certain problem.

As I don't know what the name of these different properties in my objects should be, I can't do like this:

```
var list = new ArrayList();

var obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.ID = 1,
obj.Product = "Pie",
obj.Days = 1,
obj.QTY = 65

list.Add(obj);
```

Let me explain my situation: I wish to get data from a random DB (I don't know which, but building a connection string from the information I get from the UI), therefore I don't know what data I need to get. This could be an example of a DB table

TABLE Sale

- ID: int,
- Product: nvarchar(100),
- Days: int,
- QTY: bigint

This could be another exmaple:

TABLE Foobar

- Id: int,
- Days: int
- QTY: bigint
- Product_Id: int
- Department_Id: int

As you see, I don't know what the DB looks like (this is 100% anonymous, therefore it needs to be 100% dynamic), and the data I want to return should look like a well constructed JSON, like so:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Product": "Pie"
    "Days": 1,
    "QTY": 65
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Product": "Melons"
    "Days": 5,
    "QTY": 12
  }
]
```

Or, with the other example:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Days": 2,
    "QTY": 56,
    "Product_Id": 5,
    "Department_Id": 2
  }
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Days": 6,
    "QTY": 12,
    "Product_Id": 2,
    "Department_Id": 5
  }
]
```

I've tried working with these `ExpandoObject`s, but can't seem to make it work, as I can't do what's illustrated in the top of this question (*I don't know the names of the properties*). Is there a way for me to say something like:

```
var obj = new ExpandoObject();
var propName = "Product";

var obj.propName = "Pie"

Console.WriteLine("Let's print!: " + obj.Product);

//OUTPUT
Let's print!: Pie
```

Does anyone have a solution, og simply guidance to a structure, that might solve this situation?

Comment: what language are you using? you tagged C# but some of your code is Java (i.e System.out.printline) - .NET does not have this.

Comment: I didn't copy paste any code. I just can't remember what it's called in C#. This is pure C# and nothing else. My apologies. Will correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# setting/getting the class properties by string name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283206/c-sharp-setting-getting-the-class-properties-by-string-name)

Comment: I would stay away from the ExpandoObject and do it with Reflection. This way you can create whole Classes at Runtime by getting the propertynames from the DB-Reader itself.

Comment: @KarmaEDV Reflection? Never worked with it? Could you guide me towards a link expaining what this is?

Comment: Or just use a dictionary. You can serialize that to a json object too.

Comment: Just create a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`.  If you serialize that to JSON with, say, [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you will get what you want.

Comment: @GSerg Which `ExpandoObject` is :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than creating an `ExpandoObject` or some other dynamic type, you could create a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` where each `Dictionary<string, object>` contains the name/value pairs you want to serialize.  Then serialize to JSON using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (or [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), though that is less flexible):

```
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        // Build a dictionary entry using a dictionary initializer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx
        list.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "ID", 1 }, {"Product", "Pie"}, {"Days", 1}, {"QTY", 65} });

        // Build a dictionary entry incrementally
        // See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict["ID"] = 2;
        dict["Product"] = "Melons";
        dict["Days"] = 5;
        dict["QTY"] = 12;
        list.Add(dict);

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented));
        Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list));
```

The first outputs:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "ID": 1,
>     "Product": "Pie",
>     "Days": 1,
>     "QTY": 65
>   },
>   {
>     "ID": 2,
>     "Product": "Melons",
>     "Days": 5,
>     "QTY": 12
>   }
> ]
> ```

The second outputs the same without the indentation:

> ```
> [{"ID":1,"Product":"Pie","Days":1,"QTY":65},{"ID":2,"Product":"Melons","Days":5,"QTY":12}]
> ```

Comment: Won't really work in my case as I don't have all values available, but I need to loop through them. Could you give an example? `var valueList = allRowValues` and `var clumn = allClumnNames` (Working on an edit of main question)

Comment: Dictionaries would be pretty useless if you couldn't [add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) data after you created them @Detilium.

Comment: @dbc for some reason my Json looks like this: `[{\"ID\":1,\"Product\":\"Honning\",\"Days\":1,\"QTY\":65}]`

Comment: [No it does not look like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5465923/11683) @Detilium.

Comment: @Detilium - you're probably looking at it in Visual Studio which is "helpfully" escaping the quotes in the string.  To see it without quotes, type `Debug.WriteLine(myString)` in the [immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx).  Or print it to the console.  Also, answer updated with an example of how to build a dictionary incrementally.

Comment: [Yes it does actually look like this](http://imgur.com/CsnBve7) as I'm using Postman (google Extension) as I mentioned in the main question (not using the console in VS) Postman shows the raw output I get. It doesn't care about VS. If \ is in the string Postman shows the \

Comment: @Detilium - There's no mention of Postman anywhere in this question, so I'm not sure what that's about -- your question has `Console.WriteLine()`.  But if you're posting this somehow, you may be [double-serializing your JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013632/creating-a-double-serialized-json-object-in-rest-soe-c-sharp) somehow.

Comment: @dbc I did double serialize. Everything works now. Thank you for spending time in here. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here [ExpandoObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), the `ExpandoObject` is implementing `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you can use that fact like

```
IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();
var propName = "Product";
obj[propName] = "Pie"
Console.WriteLine("Let's print!: " + obj[propName]);
// Verify it's working
Console.WriteLine("Let's print again!: " + ((dynamic)obj).Product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dynamic`, then cast to `IDictionary<string, object>` to loop through your properties:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Product = "Pie";
obj.Quantity = 2;

// Loop through all added properties       
foreach(var prop in (IDictionary<string, object>)obj)
{
  Console.WriteLine(prop.Key + " : " + prop.Value);
}
```

I've made a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yFLy2u

Now this is a solution to your question... other answers like @dbc's might be better suited to the problem (which is not the question, really)

Answer (score 1):

While I was writing the answer, I see you already got proper answer. You can use a `Dictionary<string, onject>` or even `Tuple`.

But as per your original question, you wanted to add properties dynamically. For that you can refer to other answer using `ExpandoObject`. This is just the same solution (using `ExpandoObject` to dynamically add properties) with classes similar to your code.

```
//example classes
public class DictKey
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public DictKey(string name) { DisplayName = name; }
}

public class DictValue
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public DictValue(int idx) { ColumnIndex = idx; }
}

//utility method
public static IDictionary<string, object> GetExpando(KeyValuePair<DictKey, List<DictValue>> dictPair)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();
    dynamicObject["Station"] = dictPair.Key.DisplayName;
    foreach (var item in dictPair.Value)
    {
        dynamicObject["Month" + (item.ColumnIndex + 1)] = item;
    }
    return dynamicObject;
}
```

Ans usage example:

```
var dictionaryByMonth = new Dictionary<DictKey, List<DictValue>>();
dictionaryByMonth.Add(new DictKey("Set1"), new List<DictValue> { new DictValue(0), new DictValue(2), new DictValue(4), new DictValue(6), new DictValue(8) });
dictionaryByMonth.Add(new DictKey("Set2"), new List<DictValue> { new DictValue(1), new DictValue(2), new DictValue(5), new DictValue(6), new DictValue(11) });

var rowsByMonth = dictionaryByMonth.Select(item => GetExpando(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

First part, read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx) by C# team thoroughly.

Lets see your code

```
var obj = new ExpandoObject();
var propName = "Product";

var obj.propName = "Pie"

Console.WriteLine("Let's print!: " + obj.Product);

//OUTPUT
Let's print!: Pie
```

In your code you are using `var obj = new ExpandoObject();`, so you are creating a statically typed object of type `ExpandableObject`. In the blog they specifically call out

> **I didn’t write ExpandoObject contact = new ExpandoObject(), because if I did contact would be a statically-typed object of the ExpandoObject type.** And of course, statically-typed variables cannot add members at run time. So I used the new dynamic keyword instead of a type declaration, and since ExpandoObject supports dynamic operations, the code works

So if you rewrite your code to use `dynamic obj`, and add the dynamic properties as properties it should work!

**But for your particular use case you better use Dictionaries as suggested above by @dbc**

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Product= "Pie"    
Console.WriteLine("Let's print!: " + obj.Product);    
//OUTPUT
Let's print!: Pie
```

Comment: Neither his nor your code will work. They will not even compile. When you get them to compile by removing an unwanted `var` and adding a missing `;`, you will see it does not do what you expect and throws an exception instead of printing "Pie", because this code adds property `propName` to `obj`, not property `Product`.

Comment: c**p, i noticed only the static type as the problem. will edit my answer to fix them too. I don't have access to Visual studio at the moment, came to SO for something else, saw this!